# ngClass using evaluated expression drops common classes

Tags: angular

When I use ngClass with multiple expressions with common classes, the common class `c1` is dropped when the expression changes from false to true:

```
<span [ngClass]="{'c1 c2' : showTwo, 'c1 c3' : showThree, 'c1 c4' : showFour}" ></span>
```

To overcome this I have to specify the common class using the standard `class` attribute.

```
<span class="c1" [ngClass]="{'c2' : showTwo, 'c3' : showThree, 'c4' : showFour}" ></span>
```

Is there a better way of achieving this? or is it a bug with Angular2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not supported.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5763#issuecomment-163710342

> So we are kind of saying "I want to have and not have `foo` class at the same time" which obviously doesn't make sense. It is an order of class addition / removal that will lead to different results - this is not something deterministic.
>
> I guess you need to change your code to be sth like: `[ng-class]="{'active has-error': isOn, 'disabled has-success': isDisabled, 'has-feedback': isOn || isDisabled}"`.

Further down the github discussion

> `[ng-class]="{'active has-error has-feedback': isOn, 'disabled has-success has-feedback': isDisabled}"` can be broken down to:
>
> 1.1: If isOn evaluates to true, add classes active, has-error and has-feedback.
>
> 1.2: If isOn evaluates to false, remove classes active, has-error and has-feedback.
>
> 2.1: If isDisabled evaluates to true, add classes disabled, has-success and has-feedback.
>
> 2.2: If isDisabled evaluates to false, remove classes disabled, has-success and has-feedback.
>
> There is no way to keep track of how the classes were added to the element's classList or who added them and it's not ng-class' purpose to do so. It just applies the rules it knows about.

Comment: Thanks, a github discussion was exactly what I'm after but couldn't find

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to dynamically apply/remove a class twice? If class `c1` is always needed add it to the `class="c1"` attribute and use `[ngClass]` for any conditional stuff. Is not a bug, it the building blocks html and css.

Comment: Specifically with [icon fonts](http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/), where two classes are required to display. They are intrinsically linked, so I'm looking to keep the relationship explicit within the code.

Comment: Think about it the other way around the ngClass is always going to be true or false so will always have one of the optional classes applied, so having an explicate class declared on the attribute is never going to be an issue, there will always be the combination of two.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the logic more now. There is no way of tracking what expression adds or removes a class, and so undesired results occur

Comment: Because I need to apply it in order so that `blue background` is expressed in that way, instead of `background blue`, which doesn't work in Semantic